# Math calculation PHP

Tags: php, html

Ok everyone I made two different pages

1. index.php
2. test.php

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> <form method="get" action="test.php"> 
Your Population:<input type="text" name="pop" value="<?php echo $pop;?>"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form><br><br><p></a>
</body>
</html>
```

and test.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$min = ($pop * 20 / 100);
$max = ($pop * 100 / 20);
?>

You are protected from players with lower than <?php echo $_POST["min"]; ?> pop.
You are protected from players with bigger than <?php echo $_POST["max"]; ?> pop.

</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having at the moment is when I type in for example 100 into the form (index.php) the result doesn't seem to show correctly in test.php. Seems like my GET and POST or echo's are wrong somehow...

Comment: 80 Percent of an amount? `$amount * .8`

Comment: `$max = ($pop * 100 / 20) . ";` should just be `$max = ($pop * 100 / 20);` as the syntax highlighting suggests. Can you give a detailed prbolem description? _How_ does it not work?

Comment: If you have 100 ppl, you're "protected" against who has less than 20 and more than 180, right?

Comment: People with 100 pop wont be able to attack people less than 20 pop and wont be able to attack people that have 500 pop or more as well. I'm trying to make a form where someone will be able to type in 100 and submit it, and afterwards it will show the answer...

Comment: Thank you ljacqu that problem is solved now, but now I have another problem... How can I split the form from the answers... because I only want the answer to show after I entered the population and pressed submit...

Comment: I made few changes above... It doesn't retrieve my answer correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$min = ($_GET["pop"] * 20 / 100); // can be shortened to $_GET["pop"] * 0.2
$max = ($_GET["pop"] * 100 / 20); // can be shortened to $_GET["pop"] * 5
?>

You are protected from players with lower than <?php echo $min; ?> pop.
You are protected from players with bigger than <?php echo $max; ?> pop.

</body>
</html>
```

These are regular variables you define in test.php, not POST variables. So you just echo the variable, not a POST variable. When calculating the min and max variables, you do need to use the POST variable that you submitted in the form.

Comment: Ok the above seems to work but the answer it shows is 0. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: When calculating the min and max, you _should_ use a POST variable. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: `$min = ($_GET["pop"] * 20 / 100);
$max = ($_GET["pop"] * 100 / 20);`
 seems to fix the problem thank you very much

Comment: Ah, I assumed that you were using POST, I did not check the form method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$min = $pop - $pop * 0.8;  // 80% less than population
$max = $pop + $pop * 0.8;  // 80% more than population
```

*edited for 80% +-*

Comment: OP asked for 80% +/-, not 20 % +/-. I hope it wasn't the actual question/problem though.

Comment: people with 100 pop wont be able to attack people less than 20 pop and wont be able to attack people that have 500 pop or more as well. I'm trying to make a form where someone will be able to type in 100 and submit it, and afterwards it will show the answer...

Comment: Well it's 80% less and 400% more then? `Anyway, $max = $pop * 5` then

Comment: Why $pop - $pop * 0.8, why not simply $pop * 0.2?

Comment: It's easier to change if he use something like: `$pop = $pop - $pop * $percentage`

Ofcourse he could use `$pop * .2` and `$pop * 1.2` or `$pop * 5` or whatever he wants :)